# How to disable the creation of feed items when a task is created via the REST API

Tags: rest-api, chatter, tasks, chatter-feed

We have an integration between our phone system (3CX) and Salesforce. It logs calls into Salesforce using the REST API: *`/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/task RequestType="Post"`*
Those tasks have the user as ownerid and each logged call appears in the chatter feed.

[image: Chatter Post]

These feed items also appear in the users *Daily Digest* and make it therefore more annoying than usefull...

How can I disable the creation of those feed items?
It tried this :
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ld0DQAQ (unckeck *Create Feed Item* in Global Actions)
It does not help...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I disable the creation of those feed items? It tried this :
> https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ld0DQAQ (unckeck
> Create Feed Item in Global Actions) It does not help...

Did you ever get a solution to this? I'm having this exact same issue. Feed Items are still being created for Tasks despite following the steps in this link you provided?

Anyone got any help?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/162212)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there's no settings for this.

What you could do however is write an Apex trigger or a Flow that fires after after a task is created by your integration (you'll need a way to identify/filter theses) and that removes the related feed items.